# Angular ng serve issue

Tags: angular

Recently I have been trying to learn and build my first angular app, but I keep having this unsolvable error.

First it told me that it must have required property "browser target". Therefore, I added `"browserTarget": "intro-app:build"` into my `angular.json` file.

However, it gives me a new error, stopping me from being able to do `ng serve` and test my app in `localhost` and I feel like I've hit the wall on this one. I have no idea how to resolve this.

I have tried everything including reinstalling my angular and resolving dependencies issues.

Comment: Have you tried following this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Needs much more details. Please check [ask] and [edit] your question.